# How to find missing row in csv or txt? (Complicated)

Tags: csv, line, difference

Here is example...

File 1:

> 1;01812345;BB100
>
> 2;018ACBA5;BB100
>
> 3;01955555;BB100
>
> 10;01901022;BB100

File 2: (different mac adresses and missing 3;)

> 1;01866666;BB101
>
> 2;01877777;BB101
>
> 10;01988888;BB101

How to quickly determine that I am missing `3;`?  I cannot compare whole rows, because i just need to compare first integer value before first `;`

I need some automated solution because i work with list of 300 addresses and its not consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to my other answer you said, that the task is something you would do regularly and you also expressed the wish for an automatism. Here is a small C++ program, that should work: use it like `prg file1 file2` to find lines from file1 with a key that is missing in file2. To get lines missing from file1, switch the order of the arguments: `prg file2 file1`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef map< string, string > tMap;

bool readFileIntoMap( string fn, tMap &m) 
{
    ifstream inFile( fn, std::ios::in);
    if( !inFile.good() ){
        std::cout << "Could not open " << fn << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    string key, aLine;
    string::size_type pos;
    while ( inFile ) {
        getline( inFile, aLine ) ;

        pos = aLine.find( ';' );
        if( pos != string::npos ) {
            key = aLine.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
            key = "-1";
        }

        m[ key ] = aLine; // map key to complete line
    } // of while
    return true;
}

// check for each key of first file: if the key is present in the
// second file, if not: report the line from the first file 
void findMissingKeys( tMap &leftMap,  tMap &rightMap)
{
    string leftKey;
    for( auto &leftElem : leftMap) {
        leftKey = leftElem.first;

        auto it =  rightMap.find( leftKey );
        if( it == rightMap.end() ) {
            // report missing line in second file
            cout << leftElem.second << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    if ( argc != 3 ) {
        cerr << "Please provide exactly two filenames as argument!" << endl;
        cerr << "Program will dump lines with a key present in first and missing in second file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    tMap m1, m2;

    readFileIntoMap( argv[1], m1 );
    readFileIntoMap( argv[2], m2 );

    findMissingKeys(m1,m2);
}
```

Comment: I will try this code now... 

I dont get it why my question is rated negatively...

Comment: If anyone reads this, I compiled code with DevC++ (50mb instalation) and I had to add "-std=c++11" (no quotes) in Tools > Compiler Options.

Comment: This is working! I salute you! Thanks again I wish i have this 15 rep required so i can upvote your comment.
I just discovered that I can use shift + right click on inside folder to get option "Open command window here" and that gives me cmd prompt with that location ready... thanks once again for code.

Comment: I edited your code, to show me differences in both directions at once
Present in File1 and missing in File2:
findMissingKeys(m1,m2);
Missing in File1 and present in File2:
findMissingKeys(m2,m1);
@Lars Fischer

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a copy of each file.
2. remove the part after the semicolon, with a regexp replace:

   - **Find What**: `;.*$`
   - **Replace with**: (leave empty)
   - Check **Regular expression* in the lower left
   - Click **Replace all**
3. Sort each of the copies (Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort ).

   - maybe after sorting you can find the additional lines by looking over the files, otherwise continue with the next steps.
4. Compare the sorted versions: The *differences* give you the lines that are in one or the other file (your original unsorted file). There are several options to automate the compare:

   - there is a notepad++ plugin called Compare that you can install it via the Plugin Manager
   - you could use a separate program like winmerge
5. once you know the line, you can look up the missing line and add it to the other file

Another option would be inserting the lines of both files in a new file, then sort the new file. Now you need to spot the lines with the unique number in the first column. But I would use a compare tool or the Compare Plugin as described above. It makes the difference easier to spot.

Comment: Thanks for info i will try this but is there any possibility for solution without creating copies, or additional steps?
Is there some plugin for notepad or some software, to "find differences but under certain conditions"? condition is to scan/compare only integer value before first ; sign in that row

Comment: My current answer is the simplest way (that I can think of at the moment), to get what you want. 

The usual way to merge files is by appending one file, sort and then remove duplicates. But your duplicates are only a duplicate in the first column, while the rest of the line can be different.

Comment: Im thinking to create some basic application in C I could compile it if i get code, im missing few lines, when i compare first value how to skip scanning until pointer hits new row, or first integer value in new row, and when diff is detected pointer in first file only should go down entire row

Comment: Are you going to do this once or do you have to do it regularly? If it is a one off action I would try the steps outline above. I would also consider Excel and its countif function, before.

Comment: I need this application to save time at my work. So I will use it regularly plus I need it automated to actually save time.